# file download in struts2 using html anchor tag

Tags: jakarta-ee, struts2, download

In normal HTML tag, download links can be generated by using anchor tag like:

```
<a href="www.example.com/somefile.zip">DOWNLOAD</a>
```

In struts2, I stored file name and file URL in database.
Then, in JSP file, populate download links like:

```
<s:iterator value="fileList">
<a href='<s:property value="fileURL"/>'> <s:property value="fileName"/> </a>
</s:iterator>
```

By this way, File name and their links are populated. When I mousehover on the link, I can see the correct file URL in browser's status bar. But when I click the link, download dialog box is now shown. I searched the internet and they tell to use FileInputStream. 
My question is, is that possible to generate download link as above code instead of using FileInputStream?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using Struts2 you have `Action`s and `Result`s.

So, you need an `Action` mapped to your link, lets call it `download_file.do`

You create your list of links, passing in a parameter to tell struts2 which file to download (it is dangerous to allow arbitrary files, so maybe a file name would be good).

```
<s:iterator value="fileList">
   <s:a action="download_file"> 
      <s:property value="fileName"/>
      <s:text name="my.link"/>
   </a>
</s:iterator>
```

Now, in your `Action` you need to setter for the `fileName` as usual.

Once you have the fileName in the `execute` method, open an `InputStream` to the `File` and provide a `getter` for it. You may also want to get the size of the file and the name you want to download it is.

Lets assume the getter for the `InputStream` is `getFileToDownload`, the getter for the size is `getFileSize`.

You need to provide a getter for the content disposition, this will set the name of the downloaded file, something like:

```
public String getContentDisposition() {
    return "attachment;filename=\"" + fileName + "\"";
}
```

And also a getter for the MIME type, something like

```
public String getContentType() {
    return "text/plain";
}
```

Obviously set the MIME to the correct type.

So your basic `Action` will look something like this

```
public class MyAction extends ActionSupport {

    private final File baseDownloadDir = new File("somewhere");
    private String fileName;
    private InputStream inputStream;
    private long fileSize;

    @Override
    public String execute() throws Exception {
        /*
         *This is a security hole begging to be exploited.
         *A user can submit "../../../../someImportantFile"
         *and potentially download arbitrary files from the server.
         *You really need to do some validation on the input!
         */ 
        final File fileToDownload = new File(baseDownloadDir, fileName);
        fileSize = fileToDownload.length();
        inputStream = new FileInputStream(fileToDownload);
        return "downloadFile";
    }

    public String getFileName() {
        return fileName;
    }

    public void setFileName(String fileName) {
        this.fileName = fileName;
    }

    public long getFileSize() {
        return fileSize;
    }

    public InputStream getFileToDownload() {
        return inputStream;
    }

    public String getContentDisposition() {
        return "attachment;filename=\"" + fileName + "\"";
    }

    public String getContentType() {
        return "text/plain";
    }
}
```

You then return a result name, lets call it `downloadFile`.

In your action mapping you need to map that result to a `StreamResult`, here is an XML example

```
<result name="downloadFile" type="stream">
    <param name="inputName">fileToDownload</param>
    <param name="contentType">${contentType}</param>
    <param name="contentLength">${fileSize}</param>
    <param name="contentDisposition">${contentDisposition}</param>
    <param name="contentCharSet">UTF-8</param>
    <param name="allowCaching">true</param>
</result>
```

You may want to change the charset.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time.
Please kindly let me ask one more question. In struts.xml, are "inputName" & "contentDisposition" parameters enough to download a file?

Comment: As in are any other parameters required? The only _required_ parameter is `inputName` - see the [documentation](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/docs/stream-result.html). The others just make browsers behave as one would expect.